# How to send email with GMail account?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use the following code to send an email from my Gmail account. But the following error is occurred.
`Unable to connect to the remote server`
what's wrong with my code?

```
        string from = "xxxx@gmail.com";
        string to = TxtTo.Text;
        string cc = "yyyy@gmail.com";
        string subject = TxtSubject.Text;
        string body = EdtContext.Content;
        MailMessage EMail = new MailMessage();
        MailAddress Sender = new MailAddress(from);
        EMail.From = Sender;
        EMail.To.Add(to);
        EMail.CC.Add(cc);
        EMail.Body = body;
        EMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        EMail.Subject = subject;
        EMail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        SmtpClient Local = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");//--- smtp
         Local.Port = 465;
         Local.EnableSsl = true;
         Local.UseDefaultCredentials = false;           
        Local.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxx@gmail.com", "*****");//------ email user and pass in sobhan mail
        Local.Send(EMail);

***************
**Port 587 solved problem**
```

Comment: You can try port 587 for TLS. You also need to make sure SMTP is enabled for your gmail account.

Comment: Port 587 should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have set right credentials for Gmail

Also, I think that the port used to send mail to gmail is 465 for SSL or 587 for TLS/STARTTLS.

similar problem has been discussed on this Link

> [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)